# pgpool second standby shows "down" in status

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, database-replication, pgpool

I have setup pgpool with 3 nodes. Lets say node1 as primary and node2,node3 and secondary. When I stop the database service on node1, the node2 becomes primary as expected but node3 is being shown as "down" in **show pool_nodes** command. It is showing that streaming is live on node3 and I can connect to psql as well on node3 but status is down in pgpool

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
    2020-05-07 05:58:39.969 EDT [23820] LOG:  record with incorrect prev-link 0/7D000028 at 0/81000060
    2020-05-07 05:58:39.976 EDT [25653] FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
                    Is the server running on host "node1" (10.32.5.121) and accepting
                    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    Permission denied, please try again.
    Permission denied, please try again.


    2020-05-13 08:02:45.738 EDT [3159] ERROR:  pgpool_remote_start failed
    2020-05-13 08:02:45.738 EDT [3159] STATEMENT:  SELECT pgpool_remote_start('node3', '/var/lib/pgsql/11/data')
    2020-05-13 08:03:37.917 EDT [3032] LOG:  unexpected EOF on standby connection
```

On executing pcp_recovery_node command, the following error occassionally occurs but node recovers with same command after 1 or 2 more retries

```
ERROR:  executing remote start failed with error: "ERROR:  pgpool_remote_start failed
```

I then have to attach the node with pcp_attach_node to change status to "up"