# Pgpool standby server's status is "down" some time after starting replication with online recovery

Tags: cluster-computing, master-slave, pgpool, postgresql-14

I have setup a 2 server cluster system using [this](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/43/en/html/example-cluster.html) configuration examples. They are in the same **LAN**. **Master** is node 0 on `192.168.1.31`, slave is node 1 on `192.168.1.32`.

[image]

The problem is that approximately 10 minutes after I started streaming replication with running `pcp_recovery_node`, status of standby by node is changed to down, slave continues replication but all other `postgresql` nodes get shutdown:

[image]

[image]

It gets back up when I run "pcp_attach_node -h 192.168.1.55 -p 9898 -U pgpool -n 1" and same process repeats.

I have found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61775124/pgpool-second-standby-shows-down-in-status) and read further about unexpected **EOF** on standby connection but was not able to come up with a solution. Not sure if it is the only problem here.

Here are the logs:

Slave pgpool:

```
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11035: LOG:  signal_user1_to_parent_with_reason(2)
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: LOG:  Pgpool-II parent process received SIGUSR1
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: LOG:  Pgpool-II parent process received sync backend signal from watchdog
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11035: LOG:  new IPC connection received
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: LOG:  leader watchdog has performed failover
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: DETAIL:  syncing the backend states from the LEADER watchdog node
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11035: LOG:  new IPC connection received
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11035: LOG:  received the get data request from local pgpool-II on IPC interface
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11035: LOG:  get data request from local pgpool-II node received on IPC interface is forwarded to leader watchdog node "192.168.1.31:9999 Linux localhost.localdomain"
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11035: DETAIL:  waiting for the reply...
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: LOG:  leader watchdog node "192.168.1.31:9999 Linux localhost.localdomain" returned status for 2 backend nodes
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: LOG:  backend:1 is set to down status
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: DETAIL:  backend:1 is DOWN on cluster leader "192.168.1.31:9999 Linux localhost.localdomain"
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: LOG:  1 backend node(s) were detached because of backend status sync from "192.168.1.31:9999 Linux localhost.localdomain"
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: DETAIL:  restarting the children processes
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: LOG:  Node 0 is not down (status: 1)
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 26533: LOG:  worker process received restart request
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: LOG:  worker child process with pid: 26533 exits with status 256
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 11030: LOG:  fork a new worker child process with pid: 27025
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 27025: LOG:  process started
```

Master pgpool:

```
2022-03-07 16:29:10: pid 330084: ERROR:  unable to read data from frontend
2022-03-07 16:29:10: pid 330084: DETAIL:  EOF encountered with frontend
2022-03-07 16:29:11: pid 330081: LOG:  reading message length
2022-03-07 16:29:11: pid 330081: DETAIL:  message length (22) in slot 1 does not match with slot 0(23)
2022-03-07 16:29:19: pid 15432: LOG:  new IPC connection received
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 330082: LOG:  received degenerate backend request for node_id: 1 from pid [330082]
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15432: LOG:  new IPC connection received
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15432: LOG:  watchdog received the failover command from local pgpool-II on IPC interface
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15432: LOG:  watchdog is processing the failover command [DEGENERATE_BACKEND_REQUEST] received from local pgpool-II on IPC interface
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15432: LOG:  we have got the consensus to perform the failover
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15432: DETAIL:  1 node(s) voted in the favor
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 330082: LOG:  signal_user1_to_parent_with_reason(0)
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15429: LOG:  Pgpool-II parent process received SIGUSR1
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15429: LOG:  Pgpool-II parent process has received failover request
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 330082: WARNING:  write on backend 1 failed with error :"Broken pipe"
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 330082: DETAIL:  while trying to write data from offset: 0 wlen: 5
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15432: LOG:  new IPC connection received
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15432: LOG:  received the failover indication from Pgpool-II on IPC interface
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15432: LOG:  watchdog is informed of failover start by the main process
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15429: LOG:  starting degeneration. shutdown host 192.168.1.32(5432)
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15429: LOG:  Do not restart children because we are switching over node id 1 host: 192.168.1.32 port: 5432 and we are in streaming replication mode
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15429: LOG:  child pid 330081 needs to restart because pool 1 uses backend 1
2022-03-07 16:29:27: pid 15429: LOG:  execute command: /etc/pgpool-II/failover.sh 1 192.168.1.32 5432 /var/lib/pgsql/14/data 0 192.168.1.31 0 0 5432 /var/lib/pgsql/14/data 192.168.1.31 5432
+ FAILED_NODE_ID=1
+ FAILED_NODE_HOST=192.168.1.32
+ FAILED_NODE_PORT=5432
+ FAILED_NODE_PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/14/data
+ NEW_MAIN_NODE_ID=0
+ NEW_MAIN_NODE_HOST=192.168.1.31
+ OLD_MAIN_NODE_ID=0
+ OLD_PRIMARY_NODE_ID=0
+ NEW_MAIN_NODE_PORT=5432
+ NEW_MAIN_NODE_PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/14/data
+ OLD_PRIMARY_NODE_HOST=192.168.1.31
+ OLD_PRIMARY_NODE_PORT=5432
+ PGHOME=/usr/pgsql-14
+ REPL_SLOT_NAME=192_168_1_32
+ echo failover.sh: start: failed_node_id=1 failed_host=192.168.1.32 old_primary_node_id=0 new_main_node_id=0 new_main_host=192.168.1.31
failover.sh: start: failed_node_id=1 failed_host=192.168.1.32 old_primary_node_id=0 new_main_node_id=0 new_main_host=192.168.1.31
+ '[' 0 -lt 0 ']'
+ ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null postgres@192.168.1.31 -i /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/id_rsa_pgpool ls /tmp
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.31' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ '[' 1 -ne 0 ']'
+ /usr/pgsql-14/bin/psql -h 192.168.1.31 -p 5432 -c 'SELECT pg_drop_replication_slot('\''192_168_1_32'\'');'
+ '[' 1 -ne 0 ']'
+ echo ERROR: failover.sh: drop replication slot '"192_168_1_32"' failed. You may need to drop replication slot manually.
ERROR: failover.sh: drop replication slot "192_168_1_32" failed. You may need to drop replication slot manually.
+ echo failover.sh: end: standby node is down. Skipping failover.
failover.sh: end: standby node is down. Skipping failover.
+ exit 0
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 15429: LOG:  failover: set new primary node: 0
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 15429: LOG:  failover: set new main node: 0
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 15429: LOG:  child pid 330081 needs to restart because pool 1 uses backend 1
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330070: LOG:  worker process received restart request
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 15432: LOG:  new IPC connection received
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 15432: LOG:  received the failover indication from Pgpool-II on IPC interface
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 15432: LOG:  watchdog is informed of failover end by the main process
failover done. shutdown host 192.168.1.32(5432)2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 15429: LOG:  failover done. shutdown host 192.168.1.32(5432)
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330093: LOG:  failover or failback event detected
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330093: DETAIL:  restarting myself
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330089: LOG:  failover or failback event detected
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330089: DETAIL:  restarting myself
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 329708: LOG:  failover or failback event detected
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 329708: DETAIL:  restarting myself
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330085: LOG:  failover or failback event detected
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330085: DETAIL:  restarting myself
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330104: LOG:  failover or failback event detected
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330104: DETAIL:  restarting myself
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330075: LOG:  failover or failback event detected
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330075: DETAIL:  restarting myself
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330106: LOG:  failover or failback event detected
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330106: DETAIL:  restarting myself
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330092: LOG:  failover or failback event detected
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330092: DETAIL:  restarting myself
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330079: LOG:  failover or failback event detected
2022-03-07 16:29:28: pid 330079: DETAIL:  restarting myself
```

Comment: There is too little information here and you haven't followed the example you link to at least on the network level. Also make sure to not rely on external links, they may disappear. I am guessing given the time past this issue is resolved or no longer valid. If you still have the issue, line out all the steps you took and config. Since you say postgresql stopped, it is probably an issue there, check the logs. If the Pgpool watchdog detects postgresql being down, it stops pgpool, not postgres. Your pcp attach command is not applicable unless you have separate hosts. Good luck